# Service won't start in android

Tags: android

Hi!

I have a service that should be playing an audio file when it is started from an activity (by a click on the button). The problem is though, the service won't start when i click the required button in my activity.

Service class (with imports and some other methods omitted):

```
public class ClockService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
        myMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        myMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

The activity it is called from:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ClockService.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've struggled with it for an hour already, and i can't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

u got problem on below code line.u cant use `this` for context inside `service`.u need to pass `context of mainactivity` to service to get mediaplayer instance inside service.

```
 myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);//wrong one
```

Comment: Thank you ? But how do i do that ? I tried to pass MainActivity.getContext(), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Context context=MainActivity.this;then pass this context object to service class constructor and use within service.

Comment: You are wrong @SharadMhaske.he can do that.please see my answer.

Comment: u can create class that extends application class and create mtd which will return appcontext and use that mtd within ur service to get context object

Comment: that is also one pbm with his program and see that he use this inside service to get instance of mediaplayer@Lazy Ninja

Comment: I think it is OK to use this in the service. Problem is where he wanted to start the service. @SharadMhaske

Comment: u cant get context object using just this in service@LazyNinja

Comment: then what about "this" gives inside service@LazyNinja U need to understand this inside service

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you started the service 
Change this line to startservice(new intent(mainactivity.this, clockservice));

here is [a link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html) you can refer to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just realized that i forgot to declare the service in the Manifest. Having declared it, my origial code works perfectly. But again, thank you nevertheless.